# merge cell duplicate values

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the image 
[image]

```
<table id="tblSample">
                                <!--Heading-->
                                <tbody>
                                                                            <th>Super Partner</th><th>Products</th><th></th>
                                    <th>Plan</th><th>Actual</th><th>Difference</th><th>%</th>
                                    <th>Plan</th><th>Actual</th><th>Difference</th><th>%</th>
                                    <th>Plan</th><th>Actual</th><th>Difference</th><th>%</th>
                                    <th>Plan</th><th>Actual</th><th>Difference</th><th>%</th>
                                    <th>Total Plan</th><th>Actual YTD + Plan</th><th>Difference</th><th>%</th>
                                </tr>




                                                                            <tr class="getfor counter_row_0 hide_other_prtnr" colspan="" for="20" id="myTable">
                                            <td style="border-top:1px solid #ddd;border-bottom:none;" class="inner_for">
                                                Gagan                                               </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                        <tr class="counter_row_0 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Sales Play 1</td>

                                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                            <tr class="counter_row_0 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Sales Play 2</td>


                                                                                                    </tr>




                                                                                    <tr class="getfor counter_row_1 hide_other_prtnr" colspan="" for="20" id="myTable">
                                            <td style="border-top:1px solid #ddd;border-bottom:none;" class="inner_for">
                                                Gagan                                               </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                        <tr class="counter_row_1 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Sales Play 10</td>
                                            </tr>
                                                                                            <tr class="counter_row_1 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Monika_Testing_Product</td>


                                                                                                    </tr>




                                                                                    <tr class="getfor counter_row_2 hide_other_prtnr" colspan="" for="20" id="myTable">
                                            <td style="border-top:1px solid #ddd;border-bottom:none;" class="inner_for">
                                                Gagan                                               </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                        <tr class="counter_row_2 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Sales Play 1</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                                                            <tr class="counter_row_2 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Sales Play 2</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tr>
                                                                                            <tr class="counter_row_2 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Sales Play 3</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                                                            <tr class="counter_row_2 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Sales Play 4</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                        <!--   cam total total  -->

                                        </tr>

                                                                                    <tr class="getfor counter_row_3 hide_other_prtnr" colspan="" for="21" id="myTable">
                                            <td style="border-top:1px solid #ddd;border-bottom:none;" class="inner_for">
                                                Gaurav                                              </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                        <tr class="counter_row_3 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Sales Play 10</td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                                            <tr class="counter_row_3 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Monika_Testing_Product</td>

                                        </tr>


                                        </tr>

                                                                                    <tr class="getfor counter_row_4 hide_other_prtnr" colspan="" for="22" id="myTable">
                                            <td style="border-top:1px solid #ddd;border-bottom:none;" class="inner_for">
                                                RaviKant                                                </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                        <tr class="counter_row_4 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Macross Sales</td>

                                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                            <tr class="counter_row_4 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Sales infinity</td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                            <tr class="counter_row_4 hide_other_prtnr">
                                                <td style="border:none;"></td>
                                                <td rowspan="2">Sales Play 3</td>
                                                                            </tr>


                                        </tr>







<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var span = 1;
        var prevTD = "";
        var prevTDVal = "";
        $("#myTable td:first-child").each(function() { //for each first td in every tr
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.text() == prevTDVal) { // check value of previous td text
                span++;
                if (prevTD != "") {
                    // prevTD.attr("rowspan", span); // add attribute to previous td
                    $this.text("");// remove current td
                    // $this.attr("rowspan","1");
                }
                } else {
                prevTD     = $this; // store current td 
                prevTDVal  = $this.text();
                span       = 1;
            }
        });

        var count_row = [] ;
        var unique_for = [] ;
        $(".getfor").each(function(){
            var for_data = $(this).attr('for') ;
            var row_count = $(this).find(".inner_for").attr('rowspan');
            if(jQuery.inArray(for_data, unique_for) == -1)
            {
                count_row[for_data] = row_count;
                unique_for.push(for_data);
            }
            else
            {
                count_row[for_data] = parseInt(count_row[for_data]) + parseInt(row_count) ;
            }
        });
        alert(count_row);
        $.each(count_row, function() {
            var key = Object.keys(this)[0];
            var value = this[key];

            if(value > 0 ){




            //unique_for.setAttribute("rowspan",count_row);
            //alert(value+' : key : ' +key);
            }
        })

    });


    </script>
```

i just want that the empty cell filled combine with the "Gagan".in above code i just empty the duplicate name but now i want that the gagan name should be varies in middle of the cell.

Comment: this is a wrong approach only way to would work correctly is to know beforehand rendering where how many rowspan that would need rather than joining after that another way would be difficult and different

Comment: ok so then what was the right approach can you please tell the solution

Comment: Do you mind posting the html of the table (or a significant part of it) ? that would help fiddling

Comment: @AjayRaturi for that I would need to know more details and the question would not arise I will give you a similar question which needed to add dynamic rowspans .I would suggest rendering the table as such then next call a function to delete the empty row below the non - empty super partner column and then give the non-empty super partner column the equivalent row span which would solve ur problem

Comment: @Gar i update the Html part of the table.

Comment: @SachinDivakar i use $("td:empty").remove(); for remove the empty row but the allignment of all the cell is gone wrong.

Comment: @AjayRaturi : thank you, but please could you post a bit of the rendered html ?

Comment: @Gar this is the only part of html in which the duplicate values is coming and i want this to be filled and removed duplicate values

Comment: @AjayRaturi : yes sorry, i wasn't precise, that html part you posted is not really useful without the data underlying, so, the easiest way is to render the page in a browser, then right click/show source, and copy paste the rendered table.

Comment: @Gar now check the HTML part

Comment: @AjayRaturi Thank you, actually the problem is most likely coming from this generated code, the html is messed up :(  some </TR> are really misplaced , so what should be fixed first is that generation code, could you post it again  (from the generation of the <table> to </table>(in a comment if you wish)

Comment: @Gar Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113718/discussion-between-ajay-raturi-and-gar).